# Laravel: where should I declare 'url' in helper?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel. Recently I cloned sample project from github.

Author used `{!!url()}` in view

**sample:**

`<link href="{!!url('/favicon.ico')!!}" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">`

Now i need to change `url` value to `http://localhost:8080/sample-project` where should I change/declare `url`. I searched in `config` path there is no url variable.

Comment: In the `favicon.ico` context it should be `asset()` instead of  `url()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

url isn't a variable, it is (as you said) a helper function. It returns a fully qualified url for the path provided as an argument. In this case `url('/favicon.ico')` might output as `http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico` or `http://localhost:8080/public/favicon.ico`. Just change the argument to path you want, eg. `/sample_project`.